# Java replace string with increasing number

Tags: java, replace

I want to replace "a" of "abababababababab" with 001,002,003,004......
that is "001b002b003b004b005b....."

```
int n=1
String test="ababababab";
int lo=test.lastIndexOf("a");
while(n++<=lo) Abstract=Abstract.replaceFirst("a",change(n));
//change is another function to return a string "00"+n;
```

however this is  poor efficiency,when the string is large enough,it will take minutes!

do you have a high efficiency way?
thanks very much!

Comment: What is the maximum size of the string, 999 times an `a`? (since you have only three digits)

Comment: yes,very large file.problem solved,thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) to find and replace the `a`s:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("a").matcher("abababababababab");

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int i = 1;
    while (m.find()) 
        m.appendReplacement(sb, new DecimalFormat("000").format(i++));
    m.appendTail(sb);        

    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Outputs:

```
001b002b003b004b005b006b007b008b
```